# ssh-agent rendered unusable after single use

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ssh-agent, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL (Windows 10 1803, Build 17134.112), and lately I've noticed an issue with `ssh-agent`.

When I start up a shell, before connecting to anything over SSH, I first call `ssh-add`. Then I go on connecting to something as usual. However, once I exit that SSH session to return to my own shell, I find that trying to open any SSH session prompts me for my passphrase, and `ssh-add` complains that the agent refused the connection.

In `ps` however, I find that the instance with the PID I've seen calling `ssh-agent` is still live. Checking the corresponding directory in `/tmp` also shows that the socket file still exists.

I'm confused why a live agent instance would suddenly refuse connections, and that only after *exactly* one use of the agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be caused by a bug in WSL, see this link for answer: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3183

In short, it seems to happen when ForwardAgent is set to yes.

Comment: Thanks, removed the `ForwardAgent yes` line from my `.ssh/config` block for that specific host and it works again.